# Issues with JavaScript Validation onChange and onSubmit

Tags: javascript, html, validation, onchange, onsubmit

I have an assignment where I should be validating forms both when the value of the form changes, as well as on submit.  The functions themselves I have been allowed to obtain from the internet, provided I cite the source.  My issue is that it's not working? I've tested it in a browser and am not getting corrected for anything, regardless of the amount of gibberish I provide.  I thought I understood the concept, but it's just not working? Here is my code:

```
<form name="usercomments" method="post" action="cgi-bin/form-mail2.pl" 
              onsubmit="return validateForm();"strong text>
            <table class="usercomments">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="realname">Name:</label></td>
                        <td><input id="realname" align="left" size="50" name="realname"
                                   onchange="validateRealname(this, 'realnameguide');"></input></td>
                        <td id="realnameguide">Please use proper case when entering your name.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
                        <td><input id="email" size="50" name="email" onchange="validateEmail(this, 'emailguide');"></input></td>
                        <td id="emailguide">Please use the format: ernest@craft.com</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="message">Comments:</label></td>
                        <td><textarea id="message" name="message" rows="15" cols="50"
                                      onchange="return validateForm(this, 'commentsguide');"></textarea></td>
                        <td id="commentsguide">Please provide your comments regarding the website
                            in the space provided below.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="rating">How would you rate this website?</label></td>
                        <td>
                            <p>&nbsp;1=Fantastic!&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;2=It's Good!&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;3=It's Average.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;4=It's Bad.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;5=It's Terrible!&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
                            <p style="word-spacing: 2.5em">
                                <input type="radio" value="1" name="rating"></input> 1
                                <input type="radio" value="2" name="rating"></input> 2
                                <input type="radio" value="3" name="rating"></input> 3
                                <input type="radio" value="4" name="rating"></input> 4
                                <input type="radio" value="5" name="rating"></input> 5
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr> 
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="phone"> Phone Number:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="tel" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" onchange="return validatePhone(this, 'phoneinfo');">
                            </input></td>
                        <td id="phoneinfo">999-999-9999</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="bday">Birthday:</label> </td>
                        <td><input id="bday" name="bday" onchange="return validateBday(this, 'bdayguide');"></input></td>
                        <td id="bdayguide">07/17/2014</td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></input></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Comment: Input elements are empty, they have no closing tag, e.g.: `<input type="submit">`. If you want help with the script, you'll have to show it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you only have half of the assignment done at the moment. You will need to write the javascript functions you have reference, for example `validateRealname`.

You should do this in a separate javascript file and import it using `<script>` tags.

You also need to change the radio buttons from:

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="rating"></input> 1
```

to:

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="rating">1</input>
```

Once you've written those functions and imported them, you should be good to go.

Comment: I didn't include those functions in what I pasted, but they are listed above the code I included.

Comment: In that case it looks like there is an issue with how they've been imported. Have you included the functions in script tags, inline with the guidance [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp)

Comment: I "believe" that I have. Here is a link to the JavaScript file. I've imported it using the line :
<script src = "form.js" type = "text/JavaScript"></script>

http://ernestbcraft.com/public_html/form.js

Comment: OK, I see the issue here. You're not calling the functions correctly. For example - on change of real name you try to call a function called validateRealname, this doesn't exist in the javascript file. You would need to call the validateName function instead. Also you are trying to call the functions with too many parameters. If you implemented both of these changes `validateRealname(this, 'realnameguide');` would become `validateName(this);`

Comment: I can't believe I missed the misnamed function there...that being said, I guess I'll have to play around with the parameters.  I've corrected the misnaming and still am not having much luck...